# How did Crowley envision welfare?

Tags: socialism, charity

Aleister Crowley wrote

> We should have no compunction in utilizing the natural qualities of the bulk of mankind. We do not insist on trying to train sheep to hunt foxes or lecture on history; we look after their physical well being, and enjoy their wool and mutton. In this way we shall have a contented class of slaves who will accept the conditions of existence as they really are, and enjoy life with the quiet wisdom of cattle. It is our duty to see to it that this class of people lack for nothing.

Was this Crowley's way of advocating for some form of state socialism or private charity? I'm curious about *how* Crowley thinks the bulk of mankind should be cared for.

Comment: Quite possible he didn't think of it except in the broadest of strokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on Crowley, but from what I *do* know I believe Crowley would say that farmers treat sheep, cattle, horses, and other livestock better than upper caste humans treat lower caste humans. Farmers feed animals well, give them rest when needed, treat their wounds and ailments, and otherwise treat them as though they are valuable entities. If the master were to treat the slave with the same kindness, attention, and felicity that the farmer looks after draft animals, many slaves would find contentment.

Of course, in Crowley's view these statuses would be flexible: a slave could rise to the level of a master and a master fall to the level of a slave, depending on talent and drive. Crowley would reject to false equality that is sometimes attributed to socialism and the equally false equipotency often attributed to capitalism.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the whole quote. Read more. He thinks you're cattle and that the patriarchal system is the best 2 sentences later.

Comment: I've read the entire Book of the Law, but I don't see the answer to my question. In a given patriarchy, the king or master could accomplish the goal of caring for the slave class in many ways. I'm wondering which way(s) is ideal to Crowley. i.e. *How* should a master or king care for his human cattle?

Comment: @JacobIRR. Ayerek Artmin is probably right. I have not seen the quote, but note that Crowley does not want to free the enslaved persons. He just wants to make them feel comfy.